# Django - Get database records for last 7 days

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-queryset

I am trying the retrieve the last 7 days of records from my SQLite database. I have an attendance system and I am trying to display some statistics on the UI, however currently it is not working - I will display my current code for this below.

Models:

```
 class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ("username", 'email', 'password1', 'password2')

class is_Present(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    is_present = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class clocked_Time(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    signed_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Views.py:

```
# Get Count of Present Employees in last week
def present_week_employees():
    today = date.today()
    week = today - timedelta(days=7)
    present_employees_all = is_Present.objects.filter(date=week).filter(is_present=True)
    return len(present_employees_all)


# Displays admin attendance portal functions
def attendance_portal(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, f'Please sign in to mark attendance out')
        return redirect('login')
    elif not request.user.is_superuser or not request.user.is_staff:
        messages.warning(request, f'Must be admin to access this feature')
        return redirect('home')
    elif request.user.is_superuser:
        count_employees_all = count_employees()  # shows count of employees
        present_employee_all = present_employees()  # shows count present employees today
        present_employee_all_week = present_week_employees()  # shows count present employees in last 7 days

        # Gets the employees present today/week
        today = datetime.today()
        week = today - timedelta(days=7)
        # Gets employees displayed and paginated
        today_p = Paginator(is_Present.objects.filter(date=today).filter(is_present=True).select_related('user').all(),5)
        x = Paginator(is_Present.objects.filter(date=week).filter(is_present=True).select_related('user').all(), 5)
        page = request.GET.get('page', 1)


        try:
            users = today_p.get_page(page)  # returns the desired page object

        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # if page_number is not an integer then assign the first page
            users = today_p.page(1)

        except EmptyPage:
            # if page is empty then return last page
            users = today_p.page(today_p.num_pages)


        # this_week_emp_count_vs_date()
        # last_week_emp_count_vs_date()
        try:
            all_users = x.get_page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # if page_number is not an integer then assign the first page
            all_users = x.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # if page is empty then return last page
            all_users = x.page(x.num_pages)
        return render(request, "users/adminReports.html",
                      {'count_employees_all': count_employees_all, 'present_employee_all': present_employee_all,
                       'present_employee_all_week': present_employee_all_week, 'all_users': all_users, 'users': users})
    else:
        messages.warning(request, f'Error - please see logs for details.')
        return redirect(request, 'home')
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="card" id="emp_present_week">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title"> <b> Employees present in last 7 days</b></h5>

                            <p class="card-text" style="padding-top: 1em; font-size: 28px;"><b> {{ present_employee_all_week  }}</b></p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Additionally, I have attached an image for reference. FYI - When I mark a user present **today** It will show them in both today and 7days, which is correct. However, employees I marked present yesterday are not being shown in the 7 day count today. I think the potential issue could be somewhere in the following:

`present_employees_all = is_Present.objects.filter(date=week).filter(is_present=True)`

Potentially I need to loop through the last 7 days? I have tried this method but havent succeeded.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Image of the system statistics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1F3L.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your query is wrong, equal mean you only get records on that exact 7 days ago. You need to query since last 7 day till now, use [__gte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#gte) on your query (gte is greater than or equal)

It should be like so:

```
today = date.today()
seven_day_before = today - timedelta(days=7)
present_employees_all = is_Present.objects.filter(date__gte=seven_day_before, is_present=True)
```

also don't need to use chain filter, filter support multiple AND conditions

Comment: That works a charm. Thanks for the help - I wasn't aware of the __gte functionality. There also must be further functionality that I am not aware of and must explore. Thanks again!